# Synchronous drawing

Tags: javascript, visualization, shortest-path, synchronous

I'm working on my own little side project, I wanted to get familiar with javascript and I recently learnt about algorithms so I figured I'd combine the two together to make an algorithm visualization web application. Unfortunately, I'm running into a problem when it comes to the drawing of my algorithm. I want it to update (colour in the squares) square by square so the user can see how the algorithm works. All my attempts have led to the canvas not being updated until the wait is done, and then all the squares being coloured in at the same time. This is an example of me trying to draw the path the algorithm deems the fastest (because it's easier to follow/show this code than the entire BFS algorithm code)

```
function findPath()
//returns an array of directions
path = findShortestPath([startY, startX], map);
console.log("path: " + path);
ctx.fillStyle = "cyan"
showPath(path);
}

function wait(ms) {
  var start = Date.now(),
    now = start;
  while (now - start < ms) {
    now = Date.now();
  }
  console.log("waited");
}

function showPath(instructions) {

  for (var x = 0; x < instructions.length - 1; x++) {
    wait(1000);
    if (instructions[x] == 'East') {
      startX += 1;
      ctx.fillRect(((startX * 40) + 10), ((startY * 40) + 10), 40, 40);
    } else if (instructions[x] == 'North') {
      startY = startY - 1;
      ctx.fillRect(((startX * 40) + 10), ((startY * 40) + 10), 40, 40);
    } else if (instructions[x] == 'West') {
      startX -= 1;
      ctx.fillRect(((startX * 40) + 10), ((startY * 40) + 10), 40, 40);
    } else if (instructions[x] == 'South') {
      startY += 1;
      ctx.fillRect(((startX * 40) + 10), ((startY * 40) + 10), 40, 40);
    }
  }
}
findPath();
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you need [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: And don't use busy waiting, but instead use `setTimeout` to delay the next drawing step.

Comment: What browser are you using  to run this code?

Comment: i think is better using library shortest path like library https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortest

Comment: @snwflk The problem with setTimeout is that it's ansyncrhonus in that the next line under it still gets called directly after. For instance if I create a for loop where it's supposed to setTimeout(draw1Square(),100ms) the only square that will be drawn in the for loop is the last square because the for loop would already be done before setTimeout draws it's first square.

Comment: Usually, you would have a drawing function (let's call it `draw`), which, at the end of its function body, includes a `setTimeout(draw, 100)` or similar. All drawing only happens inside that function. You can see the basic concept [here](http://www.schillmania.com/content/projects/javascript-animation-1/demo/).

Comment: @snwflk Thank you for your suggestion I turned the for loop into a recursive call and `setTimeout()` worked beautifully.